# mysqldbcompare access denied but mysql command works

Tags: mysql, mysqldbcompare

I'm trying to use the `mysqldbcompare` tool but getting a connection error:

```
$ mysqldbcompare --server1=client --skip-data-check db1:db2
# server1 on <ip>: ...
ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'<ip>' (using password: YES)
```

I can use `mysql` and connect just fine, though. I setup my creds using `mysql_config_editor --host=<ip> --user=root --port=3306 --password` and tested with the `mysql` command with and without passing all the args (`mysql -u root -p -h <ip> -P 3306`).

I've checked the bind address of the server and looked in the server error logs but it just reiterates a connection refused message. I've searched online (and on SO) but haven't been able to find anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you encountered an access denied error it means **the TCP connection has been established**, but **the password you provided is wrong for`'User'@'Host'`**(a User-Host pair is a real account for MySQL authentication, not a single username).

Assume that MySQL server runs on `172.0.0.8` and your local address is `172.0.0.5`.

1. Take a look at `mysql.user` by: `SELECT * FROM mysql.user\G;`. If you can't find either of these two User-Host pairs: `'root'@'172.0.0.5'` and `'root'@'%'`, it means there is no such account. So you failed.
2. Also check the password of the existed User-Host pair from the output above.
3. Now, the connection is fine, the account exists, the password is right, the only chance for such an error is: mysqldbcompare didn't use the arguments you provided!
4. Try other workaround like: `mysqldbcompare --server1=root:password@172.0.0.8:3306 --skip-data-check db1:db2`

Check all these stuff step by step, and you will figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this command of mysql compare don´t use the default config, try to force the user and password into the command line.