# beginner having troubles working on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, brackets

I am teaching myself how to code by watching Kevin Skoglund movies on Lynda. I am having troubles on one of the chapters in the series - creating a database. I am trying to log on to MySQL but is showing like this-

```
Rosss-MacBook-Air:~ rossnyland$ mysql -user -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Rosss-MacBook-Air:~ rossnyland$
```

The password is right because when I type a wrong password it will say (using password: NO)

What am I doing wrong? `MySQL server is running`, I'm using `5.7.20 version`, using `MAC OS x`, and have tried to log on on mysqlworkbench, but message pops up saying this

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at     localhost:3306:
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Please:
1 Check that mysql is running on server localhost
2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3 Check the root has rights to connect to localhost from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines) 
4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for localhost connecting from the host address you're connecting from
```

Even I tried to delete it but no success! Please tell me what am I doing wrong or how to start over again...

Comment: Syntax is `mysql -u [USERNAME] -p` with [USERNAME] being ... the mysql username

Comment: Run this query `SELECT * FROM mysql.user;` to make sure  that you are entering correct password first..

Answer (score 2):

The password could be right, but I doubt your user is `ser`.

When you use the command-line option `-u`, any text you put after it, is the username.

So if your username for mysql is `mysql_user`, you need:

```
$ mysql -umysql_user -p
```

or:

```
$ mysql -u mysql_user -p
```

or:

```
$ mysql --user=mysql_user --password
```

Comment: no luck on each 3 suggestions you have shown me.. I have tried a different password, passwords wrong to my previous set up and still show up the same error? ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mysql_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
anyway i can delete this whole process and start over?

Comment: @Ross What is your mysql username exactly? Using my example username is very unlikely to work. If you just installed mysql and have not used it, it is probably `root`.

Comment: success! it has worked, thank you and everyone who has commented. much appreciated

Comment: @Ross Good to hear!

Answer (score 0):

1. For the Command Line Tool error, you probably provided the wrong command. It should be:

   `$ mysql -u username -p`
2. For the MySQL Workbench error, there are two possibilities:

   - You provided the wrong password for 'root'@'localhost'. Or the user 'root'@'localhost' didn't exist.
   - Your MySQL server didn't listen on the `localhost` interface. In other words, check the value of `bind_ip` in your `my.cnf` config file. You should provide the actual ip address by `--host` option in this case.

You can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48436167/7404694) I posted before, it shows you the full steps to solve this kind of problems.